# Page still refreshing while using ajax with django

Tags: ajax, django

I'm using my own custom form. Which looks like:

```
{%extends 'base_template.html'%}


{%block title%}
<title> Simple Ajax Demo </title>
{%endblock%}


{%block javascript%}
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){



    $("#formi").submit(function(event){


        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url 'haha:ajax' %}",
             data: {
                username : $('#username').val(),
                password : $('#password').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: {% csrf_token %},
             },

             success: function(data){
             alert('asdas');
             },
        });
   });

   });

    </script>

{%endblock%}

{%block content%}
<div>
    <form method="post" id="formi">
        {%csrf_token%}
        Username:<input type="text" id="username"><br>
        Password:<input type="text" id="password"><br>
        <button type="submit">Click Me</button>
    </form>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

I've got two input fields with name password and username, to be saved to the table User.

**View.py**

```
def ajax(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
          username = request.POST['username']
          password = request.POST['password']
          Users.objects.create(username=username, password=password)

     return render(request,'core/ajax.html')
```

I've tried with the GET method too. But still the page gets refreshed. Also tried firing the Ajax call while clicking the button, but it says something like multiple-dict value error. Also tried with

```
username = request.POST.get('username')
password = request.POST.get('password')
```

Comment: In `core/ajax.html`, please change `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"` and check.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `onSubmit` event as

```
$("#formi").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         /* you have type here change it to method */
         method:"POST",
         url:"{% url 'haha:ajax' %}",
         data: {
            username : $('#username').val(),
            password : $('#password').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: {% csrf_token %},
         },

         success: function(data){
         alert('asdas');
         },
    });
}
```

It is the default behaviour of `onSubmit` to refresh the page whenever we submit the form. By `event.preventDefault();` we are pausing that default behaviour.

Comment: No changes in the database.

Comment: Put id attribute to username and password inputs

Comment: Do executes the view function but no changes in the database seen. Probably request type is not being sent.

Comment: Please see the updates, i've changed the attributes, still not working.

Comment: Inspect your networks tab and see what data is going on the server and try to debug on server too if you are getting data or not by printing it. Also remove `method="post"` from form tag. That is not required.

Also in `$.ajax` change `type` to `method`

Answer (score 0):

Just modified the jquery code, works well!! Here's a code:

```
{%extends 'base_template.html'%}


{%block title%}
<title> Simple Ajax Demo </title>
{%endblock%}


{%block javascript%}
    <script>


    $(document).on('submit','#formi',function(event){

          event.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({

                    method:"POST",
                    url:"{%url 'haha:ajax'%}",
                    data: {
                        username : $('#username').val(),
                        password : $('#password').val(),
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                    },

                    success: function(data){
                        alert('asasd');
                    },
            });
    });


    </script>

{%endblock%}

{%block content%}
<div>
    <form id="formi" method="post">
        {%csrf_token%}
        Username:<input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br><br>
        Password:<input type="text" name="password" id="password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Click Me"><br>
    </form>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

But i don't understand why is document.on('submit','#formi'){} is working?